# Menu driven playbook using vars_prompt - Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have the below requirement in Ansible. It should prompt the below menu and choose an option.

Choose your requirement from the below menu

1. Add new name.
2. Modify an existing name.

For option 1 it needs to ask again ;

1. Name
2. Enter the ID

For option 2 it needs to ask again ;

Prompt the below menu ;

1. Edit name
2. New name

I have tried with vars_prompt, since I am newbie stuck with using conditionals along with vars_prompt.

```
    ---
    - name: Inventory automation for SMGT clients
      hosts: localhost
      vars_prompt:
        - name: "options"
          prompt: "\nChoose your requirement from the below menu:\n\n1. Add new name.\n2. Modify an existing name\n\n"
          private: no
        - name: "client"
          prompt: "\nName "
          private: no
          when: (options == "1")
        - name: "client_id"
          prompt: "\nEnter the ID "
          private: no
          when: options == "1"
        - name: "modify"
          prompt: "\nEdit name "
          private: no
          when: (options == "2")
        - name: "new_name"
          prompt: "\nNew name "
          private: no
          when: options == "2"
```

...

Can anyone please guide me? I have searched the web but there are no tutorials found.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - pause:
        prompt: "Main menu: enter 1 or 2"
      register: main_input

    - set_fact:
        main_var: "{{ main_input.user_input }}"

    - pause:
        prompt: "Submenu A"
      register: submenu_a_input
      when: main_var == "1"

    - pause:
        prompt: "Submenu B"
      register: submenu_b_input
      when: main_var != "1"
```